# Getting exception while converting Filestream to binary in Deserialization process

Tags: vb.net, windows

Binary stream '48' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization

```
Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
Try
  fs = IO.File.OpenRead(Filename)
  Dim bf As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
  bf.AssemblyFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
  bf.TypeFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterTypeStyle.TypesWhenNeeded
  fs.Position = 0
  Dim obj As Object = bf.Deserialize(fs)
  Return obj
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox("There was an exception while trying to convert binary file to object. Exception: " & ex.Message & " | Stacktrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
Finally
  If fs IsNot Nothing Then
    fs.Close()
  End If
End Try
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: How did you serialize the data?

Comment: Since serializing is meant to save and restore typed data, it is probably the second reason (about  versions) and `As Object` isnt helping